Spring Boot Actuator readiness probe on custom port 84 - main /actuator/health fails by 503 error , if readiness probe down
By security reasons we cannot expose Spring Boot Actuator health probes on 80 port, and we use 84 port.
In our app we have a lot of custom ready checks, so , to provide actual Readiness state of app on 84 port we grab readiness state from default probe on 80 port( we created custom readiness indicator for this, see the code below):

class CustomReadyHealthIndicator : HealthIndicator {

    override fun health(): Health {
        val resp = RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:80/ready", HealthResponse::class.java)
        val health = <grab health state from resp status>

so, our actuator config looks like below:

  server.management.endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
      probes:
        enabled: true
        add-additional-paths: true
      group:
        readiness:
          include: "readinessState,db,ping,testReady"
          additional-path: "server:/ready"
          show-details: always

the problem is - when some our custom ready probe fails - e.g. testReady, server stops process requests, so main /actuator/health probe has an error, because the exception below occurs, when we try to obtain actual ready status on the 1st line of our CustomReadyHealthIndicator. In other words, when we make a request to "http://localhost:80/ready" in our custom health indicator, we receive 503 Service Unavailable error:
Method threw 'org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$ServiceUnavailable' exception.

503 : "{"status":"OUT_OF_SERVICE","components":{"ping":{"status":"UP"},"readinessState":{"status":"UP"},"testReady":{"status":"OUT_OF_SERVICE"}}}"

this is because server on port 80 cannot process requests on http://localhost:80/ready endpoint, because readiness probe TestReadiness died.
What can we do in this situation? If I am not fully clear, please let me know))
